# SQL Data file size increased by mistake\ wrong practice! how to remove free space at the end of database data file?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012

I have 2 huge tables VISSCHTB,VISSCHDETTB in this DB, I was going to change both tables designs so I decided to take backups only for these 2 tables!! I wrote below SQL Queries

```
select * into VISSCHTB_Backup from VISSCHTB
select * into VISSCHDETTB _Backup from VISSCHDETTB
```

this takes 2.5 hours to complete! causing performance issues, log file size run up to 160GB utilizing entire Drive L space! also data file almost double size and utilized entire drive D space!!!!

I found a post should solve my issue by using  DBCC SHRINKFILE with TRUNCATEONLY [here](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4368/execute-sql-server-dbcc-shrinkfile-without-causing-index-fragmentation/), but when I tried to run DBCC SHRINKFILE at last step it didn't work!

below are screenshots and details FYR.

1- capture index fragmentation using below SQL query

```
USE PRSMS
GO
SELECT OBJECT_NAME(object_id) TableName
, index_type_desc, index_level
, avg_fragmentation_in_percent
, page_count
, record_count
FROM [sys].[dm_db_index_physical_stats](DB_ID('PRSMS'), NULL, NULL, NULL, 
'DETAILED')
GO
```

[image: Index fragmentation]

2- identify free space by running below SQL query

```
USE PRSMS
GO
SELECT DB_NAME() AS DbName, 
name AS FileName, 
size/128.0 AS CurrentSizeMB, 
size/128.0 - CAST(FILEPROPERTY(name, 'SpaceUsed') AS INT)/128.0 AS 
FreeSpaceMB 
FROM sys.database_files WHERE type_desc = 'ROWS'    
GO
```

[image: Identify Free Space]

3- run DBCC SHRINKFILE command below SQL query

```
USE [PRSMS]
GO
DBCC SHRINKFILE (N'PRSMS', 150000, TRUNCATEONLY)
GO
```

[image: DBCC SHRINKFILE]

Note\ my account has SA privilege, DB_Owner on DB PRSMS

Comment: Well, first , using the truncateonly doesn't release the space, and your target size (150000) is ignored: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/database-console-commands/dbcc-shrinkfile-transact-sql. Next, try to use the dbcc shrinkfile (file_id, size_mb).

Comment: but using dbcc shrinkfile (file_id,size_md) may cause performance issues!!  [see this post from Paul Randal](https://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/a-sql-server-dba-myth-a-day-930-data-file-shrink-does-not-affect-performance/)

Comment: well, you want your problem solved, or not? I agree with the link you provided, you need to avoid shrink, IF you take the necessary cautions previously, like Paul writes. You've made a mistake, and to solve it, that option might solve your problem.

Comment: I just tried `dbcc shrinkfile (file_id,TRUNCATEONLY)` it worked, but data file size never changed!!! something else I miss ?

Comment: Please read my first comment